# What method should I use in iOS

Tags: ios

In my iOS app there is a view controller with six buttons. The buttons work as main menu of the app.

If the user is not logged in, must show only :

1. Log In
2. Action A
3. Action B

If the user is logged in, must show only:

1. Action C
2. Action D
3. Action e

At a new fresh app start, the view controller shows the correct buttons. It takes into account if the user is logged in or not. The app uses NSDefaults to keep the session info.

But then, if the user logs out or logs in, the view controller shows the six buttons....

I need your help to know on which method should I put the condition that determines if the user is logged in show the buttons ACTION C, ACTION D and ACTION E, and if the user is not logged in show the buttons LOG IN, ACTION A and ACTION B.
I have tried in methods viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear, but no success.

It is a view controller that works as the rear part of a SWRevealViewController implementation.

Thank you.

Comment: It should be in `viewWillAppear`. However, it seems that something else is wrong. Did you remember to set the other buttons to hidden, e.g. with `[self.buttonA setHidden:YES];`?

Comment: Share some code it will help solving your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)setupButtons
{
    BOOL isLoggedIn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"IsLoggedIn"];

    loginButton.setHidden = isLoggedIn;
    buttonA.setHidden = isLoggedIn;
    buttonB.setHidden = isLoggedIn;
    buttonC.setHidden = !isLoggedIn;
    buttonD.setHidden = !isLoggedIn;
    buttonE.setHidden = !isLoggedIn;
}
```

call this method in `-viewDidAppear` of your view controller. And also after `NSUserdefaults` is set on login or logout and if this viewController is active.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use drawers...

You need to keep track of the state of the login in your app and create/reload the view as needed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Actualy it does. Just not in code as in the accepted solution.